# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: itemsCollection.remove is not a function at stClient.login.then

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-stitch

I am quite new with Mongodb and trying to create simple HTML with JS where one can add and delete user from Mongodb database on cloud Atlas. Adding user works fine. But for some reason, remove function is not recognized.
 app id is --> "facebookclone- tlwvi"
I will separete js code so below is the code for now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>myFb</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch- 
sdks/js/library/v3/stable/stitch.min.js"></script>

<script>
let db;
let itemsCollection;
let stClient;
let clientPromise = stitch.StitchClientFactory.create('facebookclone- 
tlwvi');


function onLoadConnectDB(){
    clientPromise.then(stitchClient=>{
        stClient=stitchClient;
        db = stClient.service('mongodb', 'mongodb-atlas').db('FbUsers');
        itemsCollection=db.collection("ClonedFbUsers");
    });

}

 function addUser(){
 var n= prompt("Your username: ")
const userId = stClient.authedId();
stClient.login().then(()=>
    itemsCollection.insertOne({ owner_id: stClient.authedId(), userName : n 
, profilePhoto: "NULL", photos: ["NULL"],comments: 
 [{msg:"NULL",time:"NULL",like:0}] })
    ).then(() => itemsCollection.find({}).execute())
  .then(docs =>
  docs.forEach((doc, index) =>
    console.log(`${index}: ${JSON.stringify(doc)}`)
    )
  );
alert("added");
}

 function deleteUser(){

var d= prompt("Username to delete: ");
const userId = stClient.authedId();

stClient.login().then(()=>
    itemsCollection.remove({ userName: {$eq: d} })
    ).then(() => itemsCollection.find({}).execute())
.then(docs =>
  docs.forEach((doc, index) =>
    console.log(`${index}: ${JSON.stringify(doc)}`)
    )
  );
alert("User "+d+ " deleted.");


}

</script>
 </head>


 <body onload="onLoadConnectDB()">


<p>Hello My App</p>

<div id="wlcom" align="center">
<button name="adding" onclick="addUser()">Add User</button><br>
<button name="deleting" onclick="deleteUser()">Delete User</button> <br>
<button name="logging">Login</button><br>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MongoDB `remove` method is deprecated.  I changed this to `itemsCollection.deleteOne` instead of `remove` and although it did get other errors, it was able to get past your issue of `remove` being undefined.

Using `deleteOne` resulted in an HTTP 403 (Forbidden) error.

Comment: Strange. shouldn't the same error occur while inserting either? I have no clue why this is the case for deleting. I am adding a screenshot in case some1 would like to help. thanks

Comment: You don't try to call `remove` when inserting.  I thought I was clear about why this is the case for deleting.  What else do you need help with?

Comment: I am talking about HTTP 403 (Forbidden) error. What is the cause of the forbidden error for deleteOne operation? If it is the case of permission, then why inserting doesnt result in the same error?

Comment: Well, that is a different question!  While you don't have any info in this question about your setup and configuration, in general a 403 indicates that although you are authenticated you are not authorized.  Do you have the proper required role?  Does the role name start with "ROLE_"?  If you have questions about this 403 problem, please ask a new question that is focused on that issue.